# How to get PostCSS Autoprefixer working with Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, postcss, ruby-on-rails-6

I am wondering if anyone has any luck getting PostCSS Autoprefixer to work with Rails 6?

Previous post where i determined that autoprefixer was not working.

[Is there a way to test if PostCSS Autoprefixer is working? Specifically for Rails 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423146/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-postcss-autoprefixer-is-working-specifically-for-rail)

Here is my `postcss.config.js`...

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

Here is my `packs/application.js`...

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap")
require("pretty-checkbox/dist/pretty-checkbox.min.css")
```

Comment: Have you been able to get it to work?

Comment: I do remember I figured this out. It was not very straightforward. I remember I had to kinda "hack" my way through it. 

I would have to look at that project to see how I ended up getting it working. 

If you dont hear from me within 24 hours feel free to post a reminder.

Comment: Thanks Verty00. Have you checked it yet?

Comment: @Verty00 - please share your solution! this issue is killing me right now :/

Answer (score 1):

You could run `rake autoprefixer:info` to test your autoprefixer already installed.

Also, install it as mentioned on https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails

Some property value doesn't need prefix anymore.
In my case, checking some css transition are still added those prefix.